# How to link from a webpage to Facebook STATUS in iOS native Facebook app via fb://

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cordova

I've seen a fair amount of stuff about retrieving a Facebook user profile or page via fb:// from within a webpage to direct iOS to open the profile or page in the native Facebook app rather than in the browser on iOS devices. However, I see nothing about how to do so for Facebook status updates.

The behavior I am looking for is to provide a link to a Facebook status on a webpage (HTML5) and when the user clicks on it, to have the user be switched over to Facebook's native app and have the status show up in the app. My question is specific to status updates (sometimes called posts), and not pages or user profiles.

If it helps at all, the link is presented in a Sencha application packaged in PhoneGap/Cordova.

Any help would be much appreciated. I haven't seen anything directly on point around the web.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't a status is just a type of post?

if so, you can find the postid of it and then use "fb://post/(postId)"

Comment: As far as I can tell fb://post/(postId) is not a valid fb:// resource. Have you used fb://post? It won't actually load the post in the Facebook application when I've tried it. Instead, it just shows my home newsfeed in the Facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you need to add userid and an "_" before the actual post id for it to work. most of the data you get back via graph or whatever sdk has the post id as just the single id without the users id and an underscore in front of it.

so it would look like:

fb://post/453453454_34857894375345

first set of numbers being the userid(not an actual one) and the second being the post id(also just random numbers i typed).

haven't tested going from web to native, but just tested it in a native app we made that successfully opens the facebook app to that specific post.